# How to we NSubstitute fake for Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource.ETag?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am struggling to fake the Get only property **ETag** using N Substitute.

Library namespace: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource.ETag
Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: Is it declared on an interface or a as a virtual property?

Comment: I am trying to test ETag get only property  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.etag?view=azure-dotnet   . Since this value is generated during real Azure Cosmos Db operation, during unit test this field returns null. I want to substitute something in order to have more coverage.                                              --- Tried    record1.ETag.Returns("12345");  - but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Is it declared on an interface or as a virtual property?

Comment: I ask because NSubstitute is only able to substitute for either members on an interface, or virtual members of a class. If the property in question is neither, then you cannot do it with NSubstitute. Instead, you might want to abstract it away, put it behind a layer of abstraction that you have control over.

Answer (score 1):

CosmosDB response is a nightmare to mock. You cannot do it with a mocking library.

However there is a workaround which i used for mocking in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/develop/Cosmonaut.Tests/MockHelpers.cs#L58)

You can use this method in order to create the DocumentServiceResponse with reflection. This means you can use the `.SetPropertyValue` method to set the etag value.

```
public static ResourceResponse<T> CreateResourceResponse<T>(T resource, HttpStatusCode statusCode) where T : Resource, new()
    {
        resource.SetResourceTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow);
        var resourceResponse = new ResourceResponse<T>(resource);
        var documentServiceResponseType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceResponse, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=1.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");

        var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

        var headers = new NameValueCollection {{"x-ms-request-charge", "0"}};


        var arguments = new object[] { Stream.Null, headers, statusCode, null };

        var documentServiceResponse = Activator.CreateInstance(documentServiceResponseType, flags, null, arguments, null);

        var responseField = typeof(ResourceResponse<T>).GetField("response", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        responseField.SetValue(resourceResponse, documentServiceResponse);

        return resourceResponse;
    }
```

Just do `resource.SetPropertyValue("_etag", "Yourguid")` and it will work.

You can see how it used alongside Moq [here](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/885a98151be242516ec57cd94da1747b72588788/Cosmonaut.Tests/CosmosRemoveTests.cs#L38)

There is no other way because everything is internal sealed and they are a class.